# templates function parameter deduction

Tags: c++, templates

Here is one exercise from C++ Primer 5th edition:

```
template<typename T>
void f1(T, T){}
int i = 0, *p1 = &i;
const int *cp1 = &i;

f1(p1, cp1);
```

But compiler generates an error:

```
no matching function for call to 'f1(int*&, const int*&)'
```

I have no idea why the error include a point reference? I think the parameter deduction is 'f1(int *, const int *)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way GCC indicates that the argument is an lvalue. If it says the argument type is `T&`, it means the argument has type `T` and is an lvalue. If it says the argument type is `T` (non-reference), it means the argument has type `T` and is an rvalue.

Comment: Doesn't that rule **only** apply when the parameter type is *universal reference*?

Comment: @DeanSeo I don't think you understood. My answer has nothing to do with template argument deduction. It is just about how GCC chooses to display certain information in diagnostic messages.